# Install a XCode5 on a computer that has already XCode6 installed

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, xcode6

I have updated XCode5 to XCode6. And XCode6 is in the folder **/Applications/Xcode** (not in /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app)

However, with Xcode6, I got a lot of bugs and crashes. Now, I want to install Xcode5 on my computer, so I can have 2 versions of Xcode to test on my computer. I am not sure that Xcode5 will be installed over Xcode6 or not, because Xcode6 now is in the folder /Applications/Xcode.

I've read some solutions on stackoverflow, but normally, people have their Xcode5, and they want to install Xcode6 on their computer. My case is opposite.

Note: my Xcode6 version is 6.0.1 (6A317), my Mac OS version is 10.9.4, 8G Ram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to maintain a separate version of Xcode you can download it from [Apple's Developer Site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode). This version will not be eligible for updates as it is no longer linked to the store. Just be sure to name it differently.

Here's what my setup looks like:

[image]

**NOTE**

The version on the left is Xcode 6 and was downloaded from the App Store

Answer (score 0):

When I set this up for myself, I had to create a new user which I then installed xcode 5 on, but only for that user.

Comment: Please check my solution, you shouldn't have to maintain separate users.

Comment: Didn't think of that at all. Good system. Luckily I don't need Xcode 5 anymore. And rarely use xcode at all, but may need this in future. Upvoted.